# SimpleMembership Sql Scripts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I know that SimpleMembership will auto create the tables needed for authentication but I would much rather run the sql scripts at some time other than when the application is ran.  Is there a download page for the SimpleMembership scripts?

Comment: How about [including them with your context](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) (then you can call `update-database ... -script`)

Answer (score 1):

I found a [script on github](https://gist.github.com/kenstone/3419405)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership] (
    [UserId]                                  INT            NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate]                              DATETIME       NULL,
    [ConfirmationToken]                       NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [IsConfirmed]                             BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [LastPasswordFailureDate]                 DATETIME       NULL,
    [PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Password]                                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordChangedDate]                     DATETIME       NULL,
    [PasswordSalt]                            NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationToken]               NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate] DATETIME       NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership] (
    [Provider]       NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [ProviderUserId] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]         INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Provider] ASC, [ProviderUserId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles] (
    [RoleId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([RoleName] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId])
);
```